# I am getting some error while converting the user input into integer what is the RIGHT WAY?

Tags: python, string

---- -So here is my code-----

```
print("Type 3 numbers (comma separated)")
x,y,z = int(input()).split(",")
Avg = (x + y + z)/3
print(f"So here is the average {Avg}")
```

It is about asking the user to input 3 numbers and it calculates the average of them
But an invalid literal error occurs 
later  i just putted int() in Avg variable like this

```
Avg = int((x+y+z))/3
it works but i want to know why my code didn't worked earlier?
```

Comment: It should be `x,y,z = map(int, input().split(","))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to convert string that can't be converted to int (with commas, returned by `input()`).
Try this one, it can be used to calc average for any amount of numbers you choose:

```
print("Type numbers (comma separated)")
nums = [int(n) for n in input().split(",")]
Avg = sum(nums)/len(nums)
print(f"So here is the average {Avg}")
```

Comment: Means that in user input (for eg. 4,5,6) . the commas here will cause an error?

Comment: And can you please explain what does this n.strip() means . I did'nt learnt python completely so i want to know

Comment: Yes, you can convert "5"(string) to int but when you have commas (or any other non-numeric character), it couldn't be converted to int. `strip()` removes both leading and trailing spaces from the string but you know what, in this case you don't need it. I've updated my solution...

Comment: Thanks mate    :) :)